Monitor boost asio io_context for readiness
With epoll you can monitor other epoll handles just like any descriptor. It's a relatively common pattern and enables hierarchical event dispatching.
Is this possible at all in boost asio? Monitor an arbitrary number of io_context objects for readiness (meaning events are ready to be handled inside them) from one single outermost io_context?
Or am I forced to poll the io_contexts in such a case?

why do you have many instances of io_context ?! you only need one in the entire application regardless of the number of threads .... sounds like you need to learn about strands

Because cancelation of tasks is problematic. I have connection objects that incorporate various pieces of state and each has its own io_context so that it can be easily and cleanly closed and destructed, without worrying about asio calling back into an object that no longer exists.

But this now forces me to poll all these objects to see if their event loop is ready to run any handlers. Again with epoll, this is easily done in a reactor fashion but the asio API doesn't seem to make this possible

... so you now have to properly manage object's lifetimes and do proper cancellation instead of working around it ... your technical dept was gonna catch up to you eventually.

No, I mean task cancelation is problematic in boost asio itself. If I register an asynchronous operation for some object but this object can be destructed at any time (as a result of a network request for example), you can ask asio to 'cancel', but there's no guarantee the operation is cancellable any more of it's in am advanced stage in the asio scheduler. Now imagine the callback calls back some lambda or a std::bind -bound member function. That's use after free.

However, if you bundle all the related events you want to cleanly shut down into a single io_context, then it's simply a matter of shutting down that io_context.
